# 1.16 Bukkit plugin command with player or @a as an argument

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

This is my first ever plugin and I'm coding a command that can feed a certain player specified in the commands first argument how do i do this pls help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kjHg.png

Answer (score 0):

So if you hover over the error you would get

```
Required type:
Player

Provided:
String
```

This means you are providing text, not a Player object. To do this you would need to do

```java
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;

Player a = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
```